# Notification small icon not moving to leftmost

Tags: android, notifications

I'm running my code in this emulator:

> Nexus 5X API 27 (Android 8.1.0, API 27)

I'm showing the notification using the following:

```
 Notification mainNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,"CHANNEL_ID")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_4k)
            .setContentTitle("Test title")
            .setContentText(" Click for options")
            .setLargeIcon(R.drawable.ic_4k)
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .build();
```

I need the notification icon [4k] to always be on the left-most side. When this notification is triggered, it always appears before all other except the Gmail app notification. The Gmail one returns back to the left even after returning from a snooze.

[image: Gmail notification always of the left corner]

Shouldn't the latest notification always appear on the left-hand side? How do I make that happen?

Should mention that when testing on my device (Note 9) the notification always appears on the left.
[image]

Comment: That's weird. Did you try it on an actual device or any other emulator?

Comment: @Dennis The screenshot is from the emulator - Nexus 5X API 27 (Android 8.1.0, API 27). I'll post a screenshot from my device, where it works as expected

Comment: Yeah, that's why I asked you that. Emulators sometimes fail to work as expected. I've been working as a professional for past 1.5 years and I've experienced it many times.

Comment: So this is a non issue?

Comment: Yep, don't worry. If it works fine on an actual device, it will. If you really want to be sure, try it on a Pixel emulator or someone else's phone. I guess it will work as expected.

Comment: What I really want you to do is compare the notification priorities of both the app from your AppManager. Are they same?

Comment: Just tried it, but couldn't figure out how to check the priority of the notifications! I see options to control the notification but don't see "priority" anywhere.